# Calendar css not working (Bootstrap, SimpleCalendar Rails)

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails, ruby, twitter-bootstrap

I can't seem to get the styling to apply to my SimpleCalendar in Rails (Using the gem).

This is what is rendering:

[image]

And this is the css, courtesy of https://github.com/excid3/simple_calendar:

```
.simple-calendar {
  table {
    -webkit-border-horizontal-spacing: 0px;
    -webkit-border-vertical-spacing: 0px;
    background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
    border: 1px solid rgb(221, 221, 221);
    border-collapse: collapse;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    max-width: 100%;
    width: 100%;
  }

  tr {
    border-collapse: collapse;
  }

  th {
    padding: 6px;
    border-bottom: 2px solid rgb(221, 221, 221);
    border-collapse: collapse;
    border-left: 1px solid rgb(221, 221, 221);
    border-right: 1px solid rgb(221, 221, 221);
    border-top: 0px none rgb(51, 51, 51);
    box-sizing: border-box;
    text-align: left;
  }

  td {
    padding: 6px;
    vertical-align: top;
    width: 14%;

    border: 1px solid #ddd;
    border-top-color: rgb(221, 221, 221);
    border-top-style: solid;
    border-top-width: 1px;
    border-right-color: rgb(221, 221, 221);
    border-right-style: solid;
    border-right-width: 1px;
    border-bottom-color: rgb(221, 221, 221);
    border-bottom-style: solid;
    border-bottom-width: 1px;
    border-left-color: rgb(221, 221, 221);
    border-left-style: solid;
    border-left-width: 1px;
  }

  .day {
    height: 80px;
  }

  .wday-0 {}
  .wday-1 {}
  .wday-2 {}
  .wday-3 {}
  .wday-4 {}
  .wday-5 {}
  .wday-6 {}

  .today {
    background: #FFFFC0
  }

  .past {}
  .future {}

  .start-date {}

  .prev-month {
    background: #DDD;
  }
  .next-month {
    background: #DDD;
  }
  .current-month {}

  .has-events {}
}
```

The maintainer of the gem seemed to think it was due to outdated boostrap attributes, but everything in the css looks good to me. Does anyone else seem to notice anything with the stylesheet? I am not a big fan of bootstrap and am not extremely familiar with it.

None of these attributes are even being applied to my rendered view. What is the issue here?

Comment: can you post the html that has this in it?

Answer (score 1):

```
--application.css.scss--
*= require_tree .
*= require_self
*= require simple_calendar  <- try adding this code.
```

Hopefully this will sort your problem.

Comment: What if I'm not using SASS?

Answer (score 0):

Did you import the simple_calendar.scss in your application.scss?
I just tried and it worked but it doesn't look really like the example, just the table styled.